# how does this python for loop with a loop inside the list work?

Tags: python-3.x

Can some one explain how this loop works?

```
test = ['x' for i in range(9)]
for row in [test[i*3: (i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
    print('1 ' + ' 2 '.join(row) + ' 3')
```

I thought the output would be:

```
1  2 x 3
1  2 x 3
1  2 x 3
```

I can't follow how it inserts 'x' between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take it step by step.

1. `test = ['x' for i in range(9)]`. `test` here is a list that contains 9 `'x'`s
2. `[test[i*3: (i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]`. Lets call this list a temp_list. This list comprehension takes a slice of `test` list. For `i` equals to 0, the slice will be `test[0: 3]` which is equals to `['x', 'x', 'x']`. For `i` equals to 1, the slice will be `test[3: 6]` but contains same values as before.
3. Now `for row in ...`. This will loop over what we designated temp_list for better denoting. So this loop will iterate 3 times and `row` every time will be `['x', 'x', 'x']`. So the `print(..)` will be repeated 3 times
4. `print('1 ' + ' 2 '.join(row) + ' 3')`. The `str.join()` actually concatenates every element of an iterable (here a list called `row`) with `str` (here ' 2 ') acting as a separator between them. So, `' 2 'join(row)` here will produce output `x 2 x 2 x` and finally the `print()` will print `1 x 2 x 2 x 3`.

So the final output will be -

```
1 x 2 x 2 x 3
1 x 2 x 2 x 3
1 x 2 x 2 x 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, printing the first line you will see nine x in a list, so we are generating a list

```
test = ['x' for i in range(9)]
print(test)
```

**Output:**

> ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']

Next: you could simply write it with two loops where in the first one you loop up to 3 times. And let's print again to understand.

```
for i in range(3):
  print(test[i*3: (i+1)*3])
```

**Output:**

> ['x', 'x', 'x']
>
> ['x', 'x', 'x']
>
> ['x', 'x', 'x']

As you can see from this output we got three rows each having three numbers of x.

Then, it is possible to loop and print something different like this:

```
for i in range(3):
  for row in [test[i*3: (i+1)*3]]:
    print('1 ' + ' 2 '.join(row) + ' 3')
```

**Output:**

> 1 x 2 x 2 x 3
>
> 1 x 2 x 2 x 3
>
> 1 x 2 x 2 x 3

I hope that it does make sense now! Please let me know if you want a specific explanation for anything else?